# Remove characters from computer name before a certain character

Tags: regex, powershell

I am looking to rename our estates computer names to another naming convention and would like to know how to use PowerShell to remove characters before a certain number/letter.

Current naming convention (example):

```
xxx-xxx-12345-D
yyy-yyy-54321-D
```

I have attempted with regular expression but somehow have removed the numbers but not the letters.

I want to keep the '`Numbers-D`' and remove anything before it. So what will remain will be `12345-D`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to find the position of the numbers followed by a -D and remove everything in front of it:

[image]

**Example:**

```
'yyy-yyy-54321-D' -replace '.*?(?=\d+-D$)'
```

Comment: I think I have done what I wanted with this

$string = $Env:ComputerName
$string -replace '[A-Z-]+-'